# Write to database after failed transaction

Tags: transactions, nservicebus

In my NServiceBus message handler, I have code like this:

```
  try{
    using(ctx = new dbcontext()){
        var recordToActOn = ctx.Records.Find(message.RecordId);

        code here to act on record, causing updates to other tables in ctx.

        recordToActOn.Success = true;
        ctx.SaveChanges()
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    using(ctx2 = new dbcontext()){
        var recordToActOn = ctx2.Records.Find(message.RecordId);
        recordToActOn.Success = false;
        recordToActOn.Error = ex.Message;
        ctx2.SaveChange();
    }
    throw; //so that NServiceBus can handle the exception and initiate it's retry logic
  }
}
```

I need to save to the recordToActOn the details about why it failed.  However, in that catch block, the opening of the new context fails with an error about the Transaction being in an invalid state for the operation.

Comment: Any chance of the full stack trace? I think you might want to consider moving your try/catch inside of the scope of your dbcontext.

Comment: I did try that.  Didn't make a difference to the core problem.  If there is an exception in saving the context, the Transaction is put into a state that disallows further dbcontext actions.  You see, the Transaction is initiated by NServiceBus before this code of mine is even called.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that your handler is running in a transaction scope (the default setting in NServiceBus).  Once you have a failure, the whole transaction is rolled back, and therefore can no longer be used.

You can turn this behavior off by using:

```
        TransactionSettings transactionSettings = configuration.Transactions();
        transactionSettings.DoNotWrapHandlersExecutionInATransactionScope();
```

Another option might be to use a separate transaction scope for your catch clause.  I'm not sure if you should use the *Suppress* or *RequiresNew* TransactionScopeOption, but something like this may solve it:

```
   using(TransactionScope scope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
   using(ctx2 = new dbcontext())
   {
        var recordToActOn = ctx2.Records.Find(message.RecordId);
        recordToActOn.Success = false;
        recordToActOn.Error = ex.Message;
        ctx2.SaveChange();
    }
```

Comment: The `Suppress` is the one to use